# Snapping Gridlines to midpoint of binding box?

Tags: inkscape

In [this tutorial at this specific moment](https://youtu.be/HSivqhZ7SmM?t=181) the presenter snaps guide lines to the midpoints of the bounding box.  When I click `snap bounding boxes` and `snap midpoints of bounding box edges` and try to position my guides the same way they don't snap.  Thoughts?

Incidentally the reverse does work.  So if pull out a gridline and drag the circle towards it, the bounding box midpoint will snap to it.

Comment: Have you tried to make sure you snapping stuff are on? I don't use Inkscape, but I did find this documentation... Maybe that'll help: http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Snapping.html

Comment: I've reviewed that a few times.  I can get boxes / circles to snap to guidelines, but not the reverse ... guidelines to shapes as Irfan is doing in the video.  I also tried toggling Snap guidelines and playing around with all the snapping options, but still no love.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't recreate the problem. Snapping midpoints of bounding boxes works for me.

Perhaps you have too many snapping options switched on, leading to conflicts.  Try switching them all off except for the three you need.

- Enable snapping
- Snap bounding boxes
- Snap midpoints of bounding box edges

[image]

It works the other way too, dragging guides to midpoints

[image]

Comment: I think there is a subtle difference between what we are doing and what Irfan is doing and that is that he drags the guideline towards the circle and the guideline snaps, whereas we are dragging the shape towards the guideline.

Comment: @Ole - no, it works the other way too. If you drag the guide to the midpoint, it still snaps.  I'm going to update my animation.

Comment: Ah - Yes!  Tried it just now.  Gotta pay attention to details!  Thanks @Bill - And the circle suggestion from the earlier question is genius - Thanks again!

Comment: @Ole - Inkscape has some of the best customisable snapping functionality I have come across in vector image editors. There's virtually nothing you can't set it up for, but because there are so many options you need to make sure other snapping settings don't conflict.

Comment: That's cool. I feel like that is one of the first things they teach you about CAD applications or you learn it the hard way... Like trying to get the midpoint of a line and there's literally 40 other things it wants to snap to with all the snap options on.

Comment: Snapping to guides must be activated, too, see https://inkscape.org/en/~Moini/%E2%98%85snapping-guide-for-091-and-higher